# error with php code?

Tags: php, debugging

At the end of the following code `var_dump` returns `bool(false)` in the browser. Just wondered if somebody could spot my error given that no entry exists at all (at present) in the mysql tb = "intervals".  Cheers.

```
//Connection code etc

$findinterval = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM intervals ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");

if($findinterval == false){
    $start_interval = "x";
} else {
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($findinterval);
    $start_interval = $result['start_interval'];
    $start_interval->modify('+1 hour');
}

if($date>=$start_interval OR $start_interval == 'x'){
    $insertinterval = mysql_query("INSERT INTO intervals VALUES ('','$date')")
    var_dump($insertinterval);

//....
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. I recommend http://php.net/PDO.  Your code likely contains SQL Injection vulnerabilities. With PDO you can use paramatized queries to avoid this.

Comment: @Cfreak They may be deprecated but not all servers use up-to-date php.

Comment: `echo mysql_error()` to see what the error is with the insert; go from there to fix your issues.

Comment: All servers do not use up to date php but even then, they include other apis in most cases. More importantly, that's definitely not justificable to not to learn a new concept.

Comment: @bobthyasian PDO has been in PHP since 5.1 which was released in 2005.  If the host hasn't updated since then it's probably a good idea to find a better host.

Comment: @Cfreak I don't have enough fingers to count the many times I've had clients that can't access the server or don't know how.

Comment: @bobthyasian - that's not an excuse for bad code. Charge them more to fix it :-D

Comment: @Cfreak They wouldn't want to hear my price to update via SSH. Lol

Comment: As a developer, you need to access the server. Whether client does know or not is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

change this:

```
$start_interval = $result['start_interval'];
```

to:

```
$start_interval = new DateTime($result['start_interval']);
$start_interval->modify('+1 hour');
$start_interval = $start_interval->format('Y-m-d'); // Do not forget to change this!!!
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion sir.  Nice to some people are a little more patient with learners.

Answer (score 2):

From PHP manual:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error. For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP,
>   etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

Use mysql_error() to get the last error.

```
$result = mysql_query('select .....');
if (!$result) {
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Sadly this only fixes like 15% of what's wrong with the code.

Comment: Not 15%. His question is why it is returning false. Answer is above. A full answer. +1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I did this but here's a start:

```
$findinterval = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM intervals ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");

if(!$findinterval)
{
echo 'OMG, query failed';
}

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($findinterval)) {

$start_interval = new DateTime($result['start_interval']);
$start_interval->modify('+1 hour');
$start_interval = $start_interval->format('Y-m-d');

}

if($date>=$start_interval OR $start_interval == 'x')
{
$insertinterval = mysql_query("INSERT INTO intervals VALUES ('','$date')");
if(!$insertinterval) {
    echo 'OMG, failed again!';
    }
}
```

[Figure the rest out](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/mysql_php_2.htm)